# Listing atributes from sub-elements

Tags: c#, xml

I'm new to C# but I'm attempting to load data from a xml file that's like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<adventures>
  <adventure_path Name ="Adventure Path 1">
    <adventure Name ="Adventure 1">
      <senario Name ="Senario 1">
        <location Name="Location 1" Players="1"/>
      </senario>

    <adventure Name ="Adventure 2">
      <senario Name ="Senario 2">
        <location Name="Location 2" Players="1"/>
      </senario>
    </adventure>
  </adventure_path>

  <adventure_path Name ="Adventure Path 2">
    <adventure Name ="Adventure 3">
      <senario Name ="Senario 3">
        <location Name="Location 3" Players="1"/>
      </senario>

    <adventure Name ="Adventure 4">
      <senario Name ="Senario 4">
        <location Name="Location 4" Players="1"/>
      </senario>
    </adventure>
  </adventure_path>
</adventures>
```

What I'm trying to do with this is load the name attributes to an itemlistbox of the adventure element (the "adventure 1", "adventure 2", etc.) within the selected adventure_path element in an itemlistbox. I got the selection part working and the loading to the list working. What's not working is loading all the adventures...

Basically what happens is ListBox1 loads the adventure paths all fine and dandy, I select one of the said adventure paths, and ListBox2 load the first adventure... and that's it. It wont load adventure 2, 3, or 4. So here's the code that should load all the adventures-

```
private void lst_Adventure_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string selectedItem = lst_Adventure.SelectedItem.ToString();

    lst_Adventures.Items.Clear();

    XDocument doc = new XDocument();
    bool gotStatsXml = false;
    try
    {

        doc = XDocument.Load("D:\\WpfApplication1\\WpfApplication1\\Adventures.xml");
        gotStatsXml = true;
    }
    catch
    {
        gotStatsXml = false;

    }

    XElement selectedElement = doc.Descendants().Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("Name") == selectedItem).FirstOrDefault();

    foreach (var docs in selectedElement.Descendants("adventure")) ;
    {
        XElement elements = selectedElement.Element("adventure");

        string AdventuresPathName = elements.Attribute("Name").Value;

        lst_Adventures.Items.Add(AdventuresPathName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note - you don't have closing `</adventure>` tags in your sample xml

Comment: Ah right sorry. I'll fix it.

Comment: Using `catch` that way is a bad idea. You should catch only specific exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You don't check if `selectedElement` is null before accessing its descendants
2. You are adding first adventure element of `selectedElement` on each loop (take a look - instead of using `docs` element (which is adventure) you are loading `Element("adventure")` from `selectedElement`)

Instead you should use

```
if (selectedElement != null)
{
   foreach (var docs in selectedElement.Elements("adventure")) 
   {
       string AdventuresPathName = (string)docs.Attribute("Name");
       lst_Adventures.Items.Add(AdventuresPathName);
   }
}
```

Or, simply get all adventure names:

```
List<string> adventureNames =
         doc.Root.Elements("adventure_path")
            .Where(ap => (string)ap.Attribute("Name") == selectedItem)
            .Elements("adventure")
            .Select(a => (string)a.Attribute("Name"))
            .ToList();
```

Or with XPath

```
var xpath = String.Format("//adventure_path[@Name='{0}']/adventure", selectedItem);
List<string> adventureNames = doc.XPathSelectElements(xpath)
                                 .Select(a => (string)a.Attribute("Name"))
                                 .ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure this exactly what I want, or maybe I'm just being a noob. I'm not looking to make a list per se, but add each attribute to a listbox I have.

Comment: @GiantDwarf I updated my answer to show where is your problem

Comment: @GiantDwarf that because of `doc` variable name - I didn't notice you are using it for XDocument. Now fixed. Btw it's better to name adventure element as `adventure` or `a`

Comment: @GiantDwarf make sure you are using exactly same code as I provided. Looks like you have different variable name in foreach loop

Comment: I quite literally copied and pasted the code. Am I just missing something?

Comment: @GiantDwarf that is not possible - `docs` is clearly defined in foreach statement and used only once in foreach body

Comment: alright well I did use it earlier in my code to load the first list of adventure_paths. But when I change the variables it still gives an error.

Comment: @GiantDwarf just rename `docs` variable in my answer to `adventure` and all conflicts should be solved

Comment: ha found the error... now I feel really stupid... there's a ; after the foreach thing... messed up the whole code... it works great now thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the value property  x.Attribute("Name").`Value`

```
 XElement selectedElement = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value == selectedItem).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by that? I have that line in 2 lines above the foreach loop. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: try it and let'us know

Comment: Ah, I see the difference, but now I just get a NullReferenceException. Any ideas?

Comment: @JulieShannon my downvote - there is set of explicit cast operators defined for XAttribute. It's completely OK to cast attributes or elements to string, this even much better than accessing Value property, because if node not found, then you'll get NullReferenceException